# Active Record insert query to save image in mysql database

Tags: codeigniter

Hello I want to save the image to the database.. I written some code but it is not working fine. my code for controller is

```
function UploadImageView()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $imgdata['file']=$_FILES;
        $this->load->model('Users');
        /*$response=$this->Users->Image_upload();
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
   */

        foreach($_FILES as $key => $value)
        {

            $this->upload->initialize($config);


            if ( !$this->upload->do_upload($key))
            {
                //PARSE ERRORS
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        //var_dump($error);
                        $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
                        echo 'errore: '.$msg;


            }
            else
            {
               $this->load->model('Users');
               $this->Users->Image_upload($key);
            }
        }
    }
```

and my code for the model is as follows.

```
function Image_upload($value)
{
    $this->filedata=$value;
    $handle = fopen($this->filedata,"rb");
    $img =fread($handle, filesize('$filedata'));
    fclose($handle);
    $img = base64_encode($img);
    $data=array(
        'image'=>$img
    );
    $flag=$this->db->insert('testimage',$data);

    if($flag)
            {
                $this->db->where('image', $this->filedata);
                $query = $this->db->get('testimage');

                if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
                {
                    $response['status'] = false;
                    $response['userId'] = -1;           
                    $response['message'] = "Upload Failed!";
                }
                else
                {
                    $result = $query->result();
                    $response['status'] = true;
                    $response['file'] = $this->filedata;
                    $response['message'] = "Success!";      
                }   
            }
return $response;           
}
```

It returns error that
"fopen(Imgupload): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

and
Message: filesize(): stat failed for $filedata
and
fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given etc etc 
so anybody help me to save image in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

Straight from the [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

If you notice, they are sending the upload data to the view. So send it to the model instead:

```
$this->Users->Image_upload($this->upload->data());
```

Then your data is available in the array as is also explained in the docs:

> $this->upload->data()
>
> This is a helper function that returns an array containing all of the
>   data related to the file you uploaded. Here is the array prototype:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

So you can access the data in the model like so:

```
function Image_upload($data)
{
    $handle = fopen($data['full_path'],'rb');
    ...
```

Comment: Thanx.. this is working..I saved image in database in encoded format. Do You have any idea to display this encoded image on view page..

Comment: Usually the image itself is stored on the filesystem and the path to the image is stored in the db. This makes displaying them much easier because you have to set headers and such to output raw image data as an image: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/179471/ Typical way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9177399/183254